# Can an object spin in a perfect horizontal circle

Tags: gravity

During a lab I was doing involving uniform circular motion, i was required to spin a rubber stopper horizontally via a rope. At the bottom of the rope, there was some weights. After analyzing the rubber stopper, the only force acting in the vertical direction is the force of gravity. I concluded that the tension acting on the rubber stopper cannot be perfectly horizontal because there is an unbalanced force of gravity.

Can someone tell me why the rubber stoppers are not accelerating towards the earth because of the unbalanced force?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tension is not perfectly horizontal, it's actually pointing slightly upwards. You certainly couldn't spin an object in a perfect horizontal string, because in such a string the tension would only pull the object horizontally and the unbalanced gravitational force would cause downward motion.

However, as the stopper moves downward, the angle with which the string meets the horizontal increases -- that is, the string is angled slightly downwards and is not perfectly horizontal. This means that there is some upwards component of the tension, and at sufficient speeds this upwards component can cancel the effect of gravity and cause the stopper to remain at the same height as it spins.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is horizontal there will be no force to balance weight.so the string always slants ,so that a component of tension can now balance the weight of the object.

Comment: Nice answer. If you could add a figure in it describing the forces, then i twould be better.